# Why is this CSS code only working in Chrome?

Tags: css, css-animations

Why the code to [this page](http://www.sytemaker.com/development/css-bits/slideshow.html) only works in Chrome?

It seems to work in all browsers if I only use background colours rather than images. Is it possible that images aren't included for animations yet?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

div.slideshow
{
width:957px;
height:310px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
border-collapse:collapse;
background-image:url('about.jpg');
position:relative;
animation-name:myfirst;
animation-duration:60s;
animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.5,0,0.5,1);
animation-delay:5s;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
animation-direction:normal;
animation-play-state:running;

/* Safari and Chrome: */
-webkit-animation-name:myfirst;
-webkit-animation-duration:60s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.5,0,0.5,1);
-webkit-animation-delay:5s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction:normal;
-webkit-animation-play-state:running;
}

@keyframes myfirst
{
0%   {background-image:url('about.jpg');}
25%  {background-image:url('exhibitions.jpg');}
50%  {background-image:url('exhibitions2.jpg');}
75%  {background-image:url('medical.jpg');}
100% {background-image:url('about.jpg');}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   {background-image:url('about.jpg');}
25%  {background-image:url('exhibitions.jpg');}
50%  {background-image:url('exhibitions2.jpg');}
75%  {background-image:url('medical.jpg');}
100% {background-image:url('about.jpg');}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you target the webkit browser only.

Comment: @Bondye non prefixed works in firefox and IE

Comment: "(I'm being asked to add some more details but I can't really think of any...)" Well, your definition of "works" would help. I can't see any difference between your site in Safari and your site in Chrome, so I don't know what you're asking about.

Comment: You can try add other prefix in css property like -o-(for opera),-moz-(for firefox) ,or -ms-(for ie).

Comment: @Mr.Alien Looking at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-name) there is also `-moz` and `-o`.

Answer (score 0):

You should either add the `moz` and `o` prefixes, or get the Prefix-Free library and remove the `webkit` section to fix the prefixes. `background-images` should be just as animatable as colors, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I added the moz and o prefixes but to no avail. Only Chrome displays the animation. :-(

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I think I've almost licked the problem. [Here is the result](http://www.sytemaker.com/development/css-bits/slideshow-c.html) . Still doesn't display in Opera though ...

Answer (score 0):

Background images are not officially animatable, and this remains true 5 years after this question was first asked. If it works in Chrome, it's using its own methods to animate the change to the background image without following any particular spec, and whatever it's doing hasn't been reflected in any spec and cannot be relied on.

If you want to fade from one image to another (which I presume is what Chrome is doing), use JavaScript to fade a separate image layer on top of the existing one.